# Is this Edit Post Screen?

Tags: metabox

I need to add fields to a metabox based on whether the user is on the Admin Add/Edit Post screen rather than the Admin Add/Edit Page screen?

I've tried using `get_current_screen()` but due to the framework I am using for my options, this isn't available during the hook that I need to use.

Are there any other WordPress globals or functions that can be used to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

**EDITED:**

```
function function_name( $hook ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Script is hooked via:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'function_name' ) );
```

Is the metabox you are targeting created by a plugin?  You will need to locate the appropriate hook or filter.  There is likely an opportunity to filter the metabox markup before output.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. This might be a dumb question but is $hook a global variable or a placeholder ? Thanks.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all.  I pasted part of a larger script from a recent project.  In my case, I'm hooked to `admin_enqueue_scripts`.  How are you calling your code?  See edit above.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that the function is loaded too early to get the $post global too. I get 'Trying to get property of non-object' on `'post' === $post->post_type` .

Comment: How is the metabox you wish to modify being created?

Comment: I'm using the titan framework for creating the MetaBoxes.